# Missing admin properties in KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

The [KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/v3.2.6/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.java) class has dedicated properties for the [producer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/v3.2.6/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.java#L93) and [consumer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/v3.2.6/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.java#L88). However, there is no admin properties.

While comparing with [KafkaProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java) which has the dedicated properties for producer, consumer and admin.

I would like to know are there specific reasons when designing [KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/v3.2.6/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.java) the admin properties were not considered.

So since I cannot configure specific admin properties using KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties, then other alternatives are using [spring.cloud.stream.kafka.configuration.xxx](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java#L78) or [spring.kafka.admin.xxx](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java#L84).

Here are some short-comings of the above two alternatives I think,

1. For using spring.cloud.stream.kafka.configuration.xxx, if I want to configure some properties only to admin, then I have to also set anther two properties of `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.consumer-properties.xxx` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.producer-properties.xxx` to override the admin value.
2. For using spring.kafka.admin.xxx, it may cause some inconsistencies of my configurations. Since I am configuring the kafka producer, consumer and admin clients with different properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binder will use the Boot `spring.kafka.admin...` properties first, then apply any binder properties.

Finally, you can provide one or more `AdminClientConfigCustomizer` beans to perform further overrides.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#admin-client-config-customization

> **Customizing AdminClient Configuration**

> As with consumer and producer config customization above, applications can also customize the configuration for admin clients by providing an AdminClientConfigCustomizer. AdminClientConfigCustomizer’s configure method provides access to the admin client properties, using which you can define further customization. Binder’s Kafka topic provisioner gives the highest precedence for the properties given through this customizer. ...